# Multitenant system with different customer requirement asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, multi-tenant

I'm currently working on a multi-tenant system and I already implemented the hybrid flow that allows both single database per customer and shared database based on requests,

However, certain customers want some customisations because they have slightly different processes, But I only a have a single user flow across the system.

How can I implement this customisation for a Customer without affecting other customers on the system?

Please see my current architecture

[image: Multitenant Architecture]

Edit: The customisations are mostly user journey related e.g
A payroll system, Customer A wants to send payroll to the MD for approval while Customer B wants accountant to approve before MD.

Comment: It very much depends on the type of customisations. If it is just basic logic like which pages to redirect to, then it is easy enough to store it in shared database against each customer. If you start talking about view changes or js/css changes, it could get quite complicated and you might need to consider having a skeleton site which gets updated and then copied for individual customers when they need customisation, otherwise every time you make a change for a new customer you might easily break another customer's journey.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've edited the question to give better context.

Comment: We don't know what your "payrol", "approval" and "roles" (MD, accountant, ...) look like so we can't really comment on that. Instead of "user journey" I'd call it "workflow", and you can perfectly store workflow configurations in a database table without schema customizations per customer.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about databases.

What I will do is add a json type object for their customization

like add a custom_fields column

```
Customer Table
//your properties
custom_fields : nvarchar(max)
```

with sample values

```
custom_fields
NULL //for customers without custom_fields
{"CustomFieldA" : "ValueForA", "CustomFieldB" : "ValueForB"} \\for customers with specific request
```

then on the c# end, desirialize it on a dynamic object or a determined class.

```
//if not determined
var customField = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(jsonString);
```

then access the value

```
foreach (var key in customField.Select(x => x.Key))
{
    //to get the custom property name
    var propertyName = key.ToString();
    //to get the value
    var value = customField.First(x => x.Key == key).Value;
}
```

Comment: This demonstrates the "inner platform effect" or "database-in-database", meaning you solved one problem by introducing a couple more. How will your UI or API know how to render, validate and edit these fields? How will it know which fields are present on which types? How will you query all records for customer X with custom field Y, even if their older records may or may not have that field set? And so on. This is a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: You’d rather modify each customer’s schema?  That’s not great either.

Comment: @David this answer demonstrates one of the many solutions for an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model, particularly through storing JSON in a nvarchar(MAX) column. _If_ the "customization" the OP is looking for comes down to EAV (which we don't know), then storing JSON this way is one of my least favorite ones, even with the rise of JSON functions in RDBMSs in recent years. The answer dives too deep into the arbitrary parsing of JSON without explaining any of the considerations or drawbacks, and not addressing any of the other problems I mention in my prior comment.

Comment: @David so in short, my problem with this answer is that it directly says "use JSON" without knowing what "customization" the OP wants, and that it doesn't properly explain which plethora of problems this solution can and will yield. Maybe the answer is JSON, maybe it's just an EAV table (_and_ an EAV-type table describing the possible attributes), maybe just a nullable column or two.

Comment: Thanks all for the engagement, really appreciate, I've edited the question to give better context.

Answer (score 1):

From a high level perspective, in a multi-tenant solution that operates over the same schema we can solve a lot of problems by strictly applying all schema changes for all tenants, not just those that requested the change.

> If you can avoid it, don't even consider a dynamic schema, instead evolve the product so that all tenants can enjoy the benefits and knock back those requests that are too hard or that do not align with your core product.
>
> **It is OK to say no** *(or ask for obscene fees to make it worth the effort)*

The trick is to implement any changes in a backward compatible manner, if classes gain new attributes but you don't want them automatically available to all tenants then use inheritance to extend the classes, if you have introduced new relationships, make them optional. If you have adequately decoupled your presentation layer from the data models there shouldn't be any issue in keeping the previous views that do not utilise the new attributes and effectively skin any views that do need the new attributes.

If your domain model can be abstracted down to effectively document management, the main process management and configuration aspects will not need to be aware of the specific tenant business models, only the abstract, in this case JSON or XML serialization techniques could be used [as described in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70393227/1690217).

> A good example of this is *Consignments*, *Manifests* and *Purchase Orders* in 3rd party logistics or brokerage applications, The domain model is bound only to loosely track consignments and line items by a set of common identifiers and a few common descriptive fields, but the raw content could be serialised and stored into a single field in the database as most data and processing operations do not need to be aware of the specific content or it's structure.
>
> This comes up in 3PL frequently as different carriers using different data platforms and software are interacting with the clients at both the sending end and the receiver end, multiple entities might be involved in between tbut these entities do not have any *owernship* of the data or rights to modify it during what is essentially the *in flight* process.
>
> The lifecycle of the data involves ingestion, multi-stage processing, notification and some form of egress. At the ingestion we apply specific transformations to interpret what the standard schema needs to know from the data, but for everything else it would be generally acceptable to view the serialized content in it's native form, meaning for each *customised* datatype there would be a corresponding transformation to the *standard* model and a view that can render the native form.

If the only changes are in the orchestration of the data processing, then there really doesn't need to be much in the way of schema changes to implement, other than configuration for the process steps and some state management.

Possible solutions for orchestration that come to mind are Azure Functions, Azure Durable Functions, Logic Apps or other workflow engines. Even if you already have a core API or code base that can perform the various tasks and operations you can still use workflow techniques to execute those endpoints based on configured triggers.

You could also look into a more micro-service style architecture for the processing of the data, web hooks or Domain events might be helpful from a pattern point of view, have a read over [Domain Events vs. Integration Events in Domain-Driven Design and microservices architectures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/domain-events-vs-integration-events-in-domain-driven-design-and-microservices-architectures/)